# Как реализовать такую анимацию?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

http://fabiotoste.com/portfolio

Подскажите, как такое реализовать?
Просто наткнулся и понравилось.
Интересен сам принцип реализации, может быть кто-то среди местных делал что-то похожее.

Видно, что это канвас из кода, но что-то бегло я ничего не нашел в рунете.

Comment: вот это анимашка я понимаю O.o

Comment: Что именно интересует ?

Comment: @Netahaki я думаю  вырезанные бумашки которые в центре

Comment: Ну как отрисовать примитивы,из которых состоят картинки я понимаю, а как они из них так выложил логотипы, неужели отдельно отрисовывал? и вот эта анимация при наведении курсором в область логотипов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это библиотека [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap)

Там можно найти и другие примеры подобного [раз](https://noni.cmiscm.com), [два](http://alaa.works/color-shades/)

Скорее всего это реализовано не стандартными средствами, а плагинами, но и их можно там же [найти](https://greensock.com/plugins/?product_id=4921)

Ну а вообще механизм прост: есть оригинальные изображения, которые можно найти во вкладке `network`, они берутся за основу и по ним составляется карта, которая будет использоваться для отрисовки элементов.
Сама анимация при ховере - это просто отдаление ближайших элементов от мышки

Вообще, в оригинале там используется `Three.js`, [библиотека](https://threejs.org) для рисования графики в вебе

Comment: (Сама анимация при ховере - это просто отдаление ближайших элементов от мышки) не всегда, иногда водоворот частиц

Comment: (отдаление ближайших элементов от мышки) а ещё все частицы связаны, и (отдаление ближайших) влияет на все частицы